# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\max\{1 - k^2/x^2,0\}}$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\max\left\{1 -\frac{k^2}{x^2},0\right\}}.$$

Numerical experiments suggests that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and a $1$-periodic function $p:[n,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x) = - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}x + \frac{p(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$ for every $x\geq n$.

**Question:** Can this be true?

---

**Edit (26.12.2021)** Below is the portion of the graph of $p$.

[image]

Comment: How do the numerical experiments suggest this and what $n$ do they suggest?

Comment: @MattF. I was just playing with it in Scilab. $n=1$ seems to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [Euler-MacLaurin formula,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Low-order_cases)
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty F(k)=\int_0^\infty F(k)\,dk+\tfrac{1}{2}[F(\infty)-F(0)]+\int_0^\infty (k-\text{Int}\,[k]-\tfrac{1}{2})F'(k)\,dk.$$

In this case $F(k)=\sqrt{\max\{1 -k^2/x^2,0\}}$, hence$^\ast$
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty F(k)=\frac{\pi x}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+(3-4\delta x)\frac{\sqrt {2\delta x}}{6\sqrt{x}}-\frac{0.075}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{12x^2}\,\text{Int}\,[x]+{\cal O}(1/x^{3/2}),$$
where $\text{Int}\,[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$ and $\delta x=x-\text{Int}\,[x]$. (The coefficient $0.075$ is computed numerically -- *can it be computed analytically?*)

So the equation in the OP,
$$f(x) = - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}x + \frac{p(x)}{\sqrt{x}},$$
with $p(x+1)=p(x)$ holds, but only up to corrections of order $1/x$.

The plot compares the exact $p(x)$ (blue) with expansion formula above (gold).
[image]

---

<sub>$^\ast$ The integral of $k-\text{Int}\,[k]-\tfrac{1}{2}F'(k)$ over an interval $(n,n+1)$ contributes $-\tfrac{1}{12}x^{-2}$ for large $x$, and there are $\text{Int}\,[x]$ of these intervals, hence the term of order $1/x$ that breaks the periodicity of $p(x)$. The interval $(\text{Int}\,[x],x)$ contributes the term $\tfrac{1}{6}(3-4\delta x)\sqrt{2\delta x/x}$ for large $x$. The term $-0.075x^{-1/2}$ comes from the intervals $(n,n+1)$ with $n$ of order $x$. This is the contribution which I was not able to computer analytically.</sub>

Comment: I'm afraid you're too quick to accept; I can get the first two terms but not the remainder... need further thought...

Comment: Sir, you saw what I couldn't see and provided a clear expansion for $p$, and the derivatives seemed easy to evaluate. This was good enough for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Sir, I appreciate that you spared your time for a detailed reply, especially in this holiday season, perhaps surrounded by friends and family. I hope this small question is a means to pass a pocket of good time, akin to and no less entertaining than family board games & puzzles.

Comment: corrected a few errors, it now seems to agree with the numerics.

Comment: Pardon, I'm new to this and lost at the beginning. Where does $(k - Int[k] - 1/2)$ came from?

Comment: $k-\text{Int}[k]-1/2$ is the "periodized Bernoulli function" $P_1(k)=B_1(k-\text{Int}[k])$, see the Wikipedia page I linked to.

Comment: And where does the $-1/2$ term came from?

Comment: that is the first Bernoulli polynomial, $B_1(x)=x-1/2$.

Answer (score 4):

This can not be true: $p(m+1)=p(m)$ for an integer $m$ yields that $\pi$ is Algebraic.

Comment: Can it be the case that $p = p_1 + e$ where $p_1$ is periodic and the ratio $e/p$ is  small?

Comment: @OnurOktay --  yes, that is the case with $e/p={\cal O}(1/\sqrt x)$.